# What are the pros/cons to these 2 ways of defining parameters for a web service method

Tags: web-services

I have an existing web service I need to expand, but it has not gone into production yet. So, I am free to change the contracts as I see fit. But I am not sure of the best way to define the methods.

I am leaning towards **Method 2** for no other reason than I cannot think of good names to give the parameters classes!

Are there any major disadvantages to using **Method 2** over **Method 1**?

**Method 1**

```cs
[DataContract(Namespace = Constants.ServiceNamespace)]
public class MyParameters
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Filter { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract(Namespace  = Constants.ServiceNamespace)]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract, FaultContract(MyServiceFault)]
    MyResult MyMethod(MyParameters params);
}
```

**Method 2**

```cs
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract, FaultContract(MyServiceFault)]
    MyResult MyMethod(int companyID, string filter);        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using WCF and the WS-I Basic Profile, the biggest disadvantage of Method 2 over Method 1 is that it makes evolution of the contract more difficult in the future. Parameters classes allow the addition of new fields without creating a new version of the contract, whereas a straight method call does not (because in WS-I Basic, overloaded methods are not allowed). In WCF, there are some hoops you can jump through to get around this restriction but it all lends towards a less readable, more configuration-heavy solution.

For naming parameters classes, I find it helps to think of the method in terms of the underlying message that it represents - the method name is an action, and the parameters are the message associated with that action. If you tell WCF to generate message contracts (when you add a service reference) you'll get to see all of that stuff, and it can sometimes help understand how it hangs together, although it does make the API more verbose and is unnecessary most of the time.